# How do I make Jest not show me a summary of all the skipped tests?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I frequently run a single test, either with `it.only` or `test.only` or with the `--testPathPattern='somepattern'` options. I'll often watch the output in my terminal.

When I do, I can't see the output from my particular test, because Jest insists on showing me a summary of all the tests I skipped.

[image]

This goes on for many pages, hiding the test output I am trying to watch.

**How can I stop jest from telling me the names of all the tests I skipped?**

I've looked in the [Jest config guide](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html) but can't find the option.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You set displaying the "individual test results with the test suite hierarchy" with the [verbose option](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#verbose-boolean), but it's boolean and can't be disabled for the skipped tests only.

Whenever you're running only specific tests you can pass:

##### **`cli (npm)`**

```
npm test -- --testPathPattern='somepattern' --verbose=false
```

##### **`cli (yarn)`**

```
yarn test --testPathPattern='somepattern' --verbose=false
```

or disable it from the configuration, which you probably wouldn't want

##### **`package.json`** (a bit more permanent)

```json
{
  //...
  "jest": {
    "verbose": false
  }
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. @mikemaccana is there anything wrong with the above?

Comment: @NinoFiliu not at all thanks for reminder

Comment: With my current Jest 29.7.0, when running with --verbose=false gives even MORE logs. This feels correct given the documentation https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#--verbose. However, setting `verbose: false` in the configuration file worked.