# How to prevent Jest from printing all skipped tests?

Tags: jestjs

I'm trying to run just one Jest test, and am I using the following command:

> jest --config=jest.config.js --runInBand --bail --forceExit "services_rest_Api" "-t" "should list all tag notes"

With the following config:

```js
module.exports = {
    testMatch: [
        '**/tests/**/*.js',
    ],
    testPathIgnorePatterns: [
        '/node_modules/',
        'tests/support/',
        'test-utils.js',
        'file_api_driver.js',
    ],
    testEnvironment: 'node',
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./jest.setup.js'],
};
```

Whenever I run this, it displays the filtered test on top, but also all the skipped one below:

```
 PASS  tests/services_rest_Api.js
  services_rest_Api
    ✓ should list all tag notes (852 ms)
    ○ skipped should ping
    ○ skipped should handle Not Found errors
    ○ skipped should get folders
    // ... And many more of these
```

Which means I need to scroll up by a lot to actually see the results for the test I was running. So I'm wondering, is there any way to prevent Jest from printing all these skipped tests? I didn't include the `verbose` anywhere so I thought it shouldn't print this but it still does. Any idea?

Comment: you can run jest with explicitly disabled verbosity `jest --verbose=false`

Comment: Yes that was it, thank you. So I guess the default is verbose then?

Comment: it should be [false by default](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#verbose-boolean)

Comment: But I've just tested to verify that if it's not configured and you specify a path `yarn test ./path/to/test` it's verbose

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for the help. Feel free to add your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make Jest not show me a summary of all the skipped tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60568275/how-do-i-make-jest-not-show-me-a-summary-of-all-the-skipped-tests)

Comment: @EliasZamaria, why do you come with that 18 months later? What answers the question is, well, the answer to the question below.

Comment: Hmm... the questions definitely seem like duplicates of each other. I closed this one because it was newer, but I'm wondering if that was the right thing to do. Would it be better to retract my close vote for this question and vote to close the other one? Or can they somehow be merged?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To disable verbosity you could either set it:

**`cli`**

```sh
jest --verbose=false
```

or in:

**`jest.config.json/package.json`**

```json
{
   "verbose": false
}
```

and even the documentations says by default it's [`false` by default](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#verbose-boolean)

it's enabled when you run tests for a single file

Comment: This does hide the skipped tests but also hides the tests which ran unfortunately.